# Why are there so many types of mincha offering?

Tags: korban, mincha-meal-offering

There is only one method of offering each category of animal and bird sacrifices. Similarly, incense can be offered in only one way. But one can choose to offer a voluntary mincha in 4 ways (flour, griddle, deep pan, or baked). Why is there so much flexibility in the mincha offering?

Comment: I don't get it. A goat could be an olah or a chatat or an asham or a shlamim. Why so many kinds?

Comment: An Olah and a chatat and an asham are completely different sacrifices with different purposes (forgiveness, celebration, etc). I'm asking about the voluntary mincha, which has 4 different recipes for the same sacrifice.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.447.2?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah&lang=he

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Yehoyada_on_Menachot.104b.1?vhe=Senlake_edition_2019_based_on_Ben_Yehoyada,_Jerusalem,_1897&lang=bi&p2=Menachot.104b.11&lang2=bi

Comment: One could choose to offer a voluntary olah of: bull, calf, ram, lamb, goat, kid, turtledove, pigeon

Comment: @Daniel no those are just different procedures for the same sacrifice: goat offering.

Comment: @JoelK But there the ingredients are different. Here both the ingredients and the reason to bring the sacrifice are the same, but there are 4 different procedures.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Torat_HaOlah%2C_Part_Two.27.1?vhe=Torat_HaOlah,_based_on_Prague,_1570_and_Lemberg,_1858_editions_&lang=he

Comment: I have to imagine that there are some good essays about this in Torah Shelemah